# Вывод отредактирвоанных цен на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый!
Нужно сделать следующее:
На странице сайта выводится 10 товаров (кол-во может быть разным). Нужно взять каждую цену, и уменьшить ее на 15 процентов и вывести обновленную.
Сейчас все задачи сделаны, кроме подстановки отредактированных цен к нужным товарам

```
var searchItem = $('.booking-list .change-price');   /*сбор всех цен со страницы*/
for (var i=0; i<searchItem.length; i++) {
    var searchPriceArr = $(searchItem[i]).text().trim().slice(0, -2).split(''); /*переводим цены в массивы*/
    var mySearchPriceArr = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < searchPriceArr.length; j++) {
        if ( j in searchPriceArr ) {
            mySearchPriceArr.push(searchPriceArr[j]);
        }
    }

    mySearchPriceArr = mySearchPriceArr.clean(' ');/*  убираем пробелы в цене*/
    var mySearchPriceNumb = mySearchPriceArr.join(''); /*склеиваем цену в строку*/
    var mySearchPriceNumbClear = mySearchPriceNumb - mySearchPriceNumb * 15/100; /*получаем цену на 15 процентов меньше*/

    console.log(mySearchPriceNumbClear); /*тут выводятся все цены отредактиванные в консоль*/

    $('.booking-list li:nth-child('i') .change-price').text(mySearchPriceNumbClear + ' ₽'); /*это моя попытка вывести новые цены, но он не удачная. Подставлять нужно сюда - .booking-list li .change-price*/
}
```

Comment: изучите метод each(), тогда в for() необходимость отпадет.

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка в подставлении `i` в `string`

```
' + i + '
```

но вообще лучше в цикле итем брать

```
var item = $(searchItem[i]);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал var item = $(searchItem[i]);